# Intent from AppWidgetProvider to Broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

I'm new at Android, and currently developing a widget that needs to send an intent from AppWidgetProvider to BroadcastReceiver. I've tried the following, from AppWidgetProvider.onUpdate:

```
    Intent receiver = new Intent(context, MyWidgetIntentReceiver.class);
    receiver.setAction("com.mywidget.intent.action.MESSAGE_1");
    context.startService(receiver);
```

with no results. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I answer myself. Just replace

```
context.startService(receiver);
```

by

```
context.sendBroadcast(receiver);
```